# Iphone CLLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am new at iphone and I have a problem.

I have this code

```
for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
    Datos *datos = (Datos *)[arr_datos objectAtIndex:i];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
    AnnotationItem *annotationItem = [[AnnotationItem alloc] init];
    coord.latitude =[datos.latitud doubleValue];
    coord.longitude = [datos.longitud doubleValue];

    NSLog(@"coord %f",coord.longitude);
    NSLog(@"coord %f",coord.latitude);
    [annotationItem setCoordinate:coord];
    //[annotationItem setEstacion:estacion];

    [mapView_ addAnnotation:annotationItem];
    [annotationItem release];

}
```

The problem that it doesn't done anything

But if i change the `coord.latitude=40.444` and `coord.longitude=-3.700;`

this gives me what I want, but I don't want this, because I have an array with many latitudes and longitudes. Can anyone help me with this? when i put `coord.longitude=[datos.longitude floatValue];`, it doesn't work?

I'm using Xcode 3.2.2

Thanks and forgive me english.

Comment: It's a NSObject, and i have some variables ther.When i make the NSLog of the [datos.longitude floatValue] this give me the value. But when i coord.longitude=[datos.longitude floatValue] this dosen't make nothing.

Comment: NSStrings. all the variables that i have in Datos are NSString.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that i had change the values, I was putting wrong values. Only I have to do is change the

```
coord.latitude =[datos.longitud doubleValue]; 
coord.longitude = [datos.latitud doubleValue];
```

thank everyone for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Datos is an object you defined since i couldn't find it in the SDK. Given that it could be a few different things:

- Either that `arr_datos` does not have the correct (or any) data inside of it
- It could be that the Datos object is incorrectly handling data passed into it and not storing it correctly.

Place a breakpoint in Xcode and verify that `arr_datos` has the information you think inside of it and that the datos object is correctly storing information.

Comment: Yes, i do that and i make a NSLog and i have the information. I don't know why when i pass the [ann setCoordinate:coord] don't do what i want. I make a NSLog of coord.longitude and coord.latitude and they have my information.

Answer (score 0):

CLLocationCoordinate2D is not an object so declare it like:

```
 CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
```

BTW, you should be getting warnings about `CLLocationCoordinate2D *coord` - can you check your compiler logs?

[suggestion1]

```
NSLog(@"datos.lon %@", datos.longitud);
NSLog(@"datos.lat %@", datos.latitud);
```

[/suggestion1]

[suggestion2]

Note too that you can iterate through all of your datos_arr with the following:

```
for(Datos *datos in datos_arry) {
    NSLog(.....);
}
```

[/suggestion2]

Comment: this is all the code.for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
  Datos *datos = (Datos *)[arr_datos objectAtIndex:i];
  //NSLog(@"El nombre en anotation %@",datos.nombre);
  CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
  AnnotationItem *annotationItem = [[AnnotationItem alloc] init];
        
  
        
  
  coord.latitude =[datos.latitud doubleValue];
        coord.longitude = [datos.longitud doubleValue];
  
  
  
  
  NSLog(@"coord %f",coord.longitude);
  NSLog(@"coord %f",coord.latitude);
  [annotationItem setCoordinate:coord];
        [mapView_ addAnnotation:annotationItem];
        [annotationItem release];
    }

Comment: please add that code to your original question, formatted so as to be readable. Also, what are the EXACT (cut and paste) strings from your NSLog?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. :(

Comment: Do you not have an 'edit' selection on your original question?  (right before the comments...)

Comment: And what is printed in the log file?  One more suggestion, include lines to print the datos.latitud and datos.longitud into your log also.  (See edits to my answer)

Comment: The value that i want. Example coord 40.421300 and coord -3.703630.

Comment: This is strange, if i put this coord.latitude=40.42 and coord.longitude = -3.70 this works but the other don't. It's very strange i don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: What I'm driving at here is that there seems to be an issue with your datos data.  Copy/Paste the EXACT log output into your answer after my suggested modifications above (which should go immediately after the "Datos *datos = (Datos *)[arr_datos objectAtIndex:i];" line)

Comment: I trie'd with doubleValue and with floatValue and the two don't work.

Comment: I put and the result is this. datos.lat -3.70363
datos.lng 40.4213

Comment: I see the problem. I change the values of the variables, the solution is coord.latitude =[datos.longitud doubleValue];
    coord.longitude = [datos.latitud doubleValue];

Comment: Thanks to whomever for the down vote after 2+ years of the answer without a single comment why.